# Restricting url access by role in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is there any way to restrict access to a given url/route in a Parse CloudCode application?

```
app.get( '/', function ( req, res )
   {         
     res.render('home');
   } );

// only allow access to this 'route' if the user making the request is an admin 
app.get('/admin', function(req, res)
{
 var user = Parse.User.current();
 // user is always null.  No way to check their user privileges. 
 res.render('admin');
});
```

The problem as I see it, there is no way to access the Parse.User.current(), or request user in main.js file.  Creating and then accessing an 'isAdmin' CloudCode function from the client seems the wrong way to prevent access by unauthorised users to urls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using Cloud Code; you send an auth token with each request; that's what keeps other people from using it.  That's what keeps outsiders out (although there are issues); to keep insiders from accessing URLs; you could do a Parse.user check each time that URL is requested.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Parse.User is always null. (I updated the code in the question).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment on your post due to my low point. But have you tried on This documentation?

Your have to use parse made middleware for its express cloud : `parseExpressCookieSession` and `parseExpressHttpsRedirect`. Then you can access user data easily with `Parse.User.current()` in cloud code.

You can see the sample code on Parse SDK reference [#parseExpressCookieSession](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/parseExpressCookieSession.html)

> [USER SESSION MANAGEMENT](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#hosting-user-session-management)
>
> You can add Parse.User authentication and session management to your
>   Express app using the parseExpressCookieSession middleware. You just
>   need to call Parse.User.logIn() in Cloud Code, and this middleware
>   will automatically manage the user session for you.
>
> You can use a web form to ask for the user's login credentials, and
>   log in the user in Cloud Code when you receive data from this form.
>   After you call Parse.User.logIn(), this middleware will automatically
>   set a cookie in the user's browser. During subsequent HTTP requests
>   from the same browser, this middleware will use this cookie to
>   automatically set the current user in Cloud Code. This will make ACLs
>   work properly in Cloud Code, and allow you to retrieve the entire
>   current user object if needed. 
>   ...

Comment: thanks for the input.  however, after logging the user into the system, the routing has no access to the user.  Cloud functions can access the request user fine, but for the basic routes, Parse.User.current() is null, req.user is null too. ie.

`app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
Parse.User.current(); // is null
req.user; // is null
});`

Comment: Did you follow the sample code? You have to call `Parse.User.logIn()` method both on client-side browser and Parse Cloud.

Comment: Yeah followed the samples, etc.  I investigated further and if you call the Parse.User.become method, subsequent calls will have a null `Parse.User.current`.  I've raised a bug report (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1468461190126524/) and sample project (https://github.com/nhammond101/ParseUserBecomeBug) as this behaviour seems wrong. @radian-jheng thanks for your input